# Проблемы со скрытием элемента по клику

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется поиск на сайте. При нажатии на него появляется сама форма поиска. При клике на вне области поиска он закрывается. Все нормально, но, после того как поиск закрылся вне области, и при новом нажатии на кнопку "Поиск" ничего не происходит, только если нажать второй раз. Как сделать чтобы не надо было 2 раза нажимать, а с первого раза все открывалось?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search_box').click(function(e) {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('#search_form').toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('#search_form').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('body').click(function() {
        var link = $('a#btn');
        if (link.hasClass('active')) {
            link.click();
        }
    });
});

jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        var div = $("#search_form");
        if (!div.is(e.target) && div.has(e.target).length === 0) {
            div.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="search pull-right search-li">
    <input class="search_box" type="checkbox" id="search_box">
    <label class="fa fa-search icon-search" for="search_box"></label>
    <div class="search_form" id="search_form">
        <form action="#">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Traži...">
            <input type="submit" value="search">
        </form>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search_box').click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('#search_form').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $('#search_form').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    if ($('#search_box').hasClass('active')) {
      $('#search_box').click();
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="search pull-right search-li">
  <input class="search_box active" type="checkbox" id="search_box">
  <label class="fa fa-search icon-search" for="search_box"></label>
  <div class="search_form" id="search_form">
    <form action="#">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Traži...">
      <input type="submit" value="search">
    </form>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Так он почему то первый раз открывается и закрывается как надо, потом он открывается только по клику в любом месте страницы

Comment: То же самое, открывает поиск при нажатии на любое место на сайте.

Comment: обновил код. Единственное — из-за отсутствия стилей по умолчанию форма показывается

Comment: А сейчас вообще почему-то не открывает)

Comment: Вы пример запускаете?

Comment: @Danil там просто у `#search_box` разу стоит класс `active`,а у Вас может быть форма скрыта в этот момент